# SQL for a many to many relationship using inner joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following many-to-many relationship between employees and workgroups:

```
employees table
-----------------
id

empgroups table
---------------
employee_id
workgroup_id

workorders table
----------------
workgroup_id
```

I'm trying to write SQL that will list all the workorders for an employee based on the workgroups that employee belongs to.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT wonum, workgroup_id
FROM workorders
INNER JOIN employees
ON workorders.employee_id = employee_id
INNER JOIN empgroups 
ON employees.employee.id = empgroups.employee_id
WHERE employee_id = 2
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  schema "employees" does not exist
```

Sorry - the employee has id not employee.id

Comment: What is the problem? What is wrong with the results you are getting from the `SELECT`?

Comment: Do you need to disambiguate the employee_id in the where clause?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT wonum, workgroup_id
  FROM workorders
  JOIN empgroups 
    ON empgroups.workgroup_id = workorders.workgroup_id
  JOIN employees
    ON employees.employee_id = empgroups.employee_id
 WHERE employees.employee_id = 2
```

Comment: I would really love to know what exactly is going on with tables and elements throughout this query

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT w.wonum, w.workgroup_id
FROM   workorders w
JOIN   empgroups  e USING (workgroup_id)
WHERE  e.employee_id = 2
```

The table `employees` is not needed at all for this query. `USING` shortens the syntax in this case. As do table aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this query instead:

```
SELECT * FROM empgroups
INNER JOIN employees
ON empgroups.empId = employees.id
INNER JOIN workorders
ON empgroups.woId = workorders.id
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fdd31/1)